# create a structure containing an array

Tags: julia

I want to create a structure in Julia which contains two floating point variables (coorx, velx) and one vector array of two elements which contains gradients with two elements, my idea is as follows:

```
struct part_struct
     coorx::Float64
     velx::Float64
     gradx::Vector{Float64}(undef,2)
end
```

However, when I try to create an array of 10 of such structures:

```
num = 10
part = Array{part_struct,1}(undef, num)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: in part_struct, in type definition, expected Type, got a value of type Array{Float64,1}
```

How could I create such a structure in Julia?

Answer (score 3):

you should put the type of the array in the struct, like that:

```
struct PartStruct
     coorx::Float64
     velx::Float64
     gradx::Vector{Float64}
end
```

Note that you can't restrict the size of a `Vector` in a struct. To do so, you can use a `Tuple` instead (it should also have better performance):

```
struct PartStruct
     coorx::Float64
     velx::Float64
     gradx::NTuple{2, Float64} # (equivalent to Tuple{Float64, Float64})
end
```

This is an immutable struct, which might not be what you want

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I create an structure called "part" as I wrote above, how can I initialize the values of the elements. For instance, if I want coorx = 1, velx =2, gradx[1] = 3, gradx[2] = 4 ? I tried for instance, part[1].coorx = 1 but this didn't work.

Comment: See the manual chapter on [constructors](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/).